# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIColor' from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uicolor

Please check the below code portion and help me to solve the warning..

```
theGraphSubDataObj2.subDataColor = [self hexStringFromColor:[clrDic valueForKey:key]] ;

    - (NSString *)hexStringFromColor:(UIColor *)color {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);

    CGFloat r = components[0];
    CGFloat g = components[1];
    CGFloat b = components[2];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02lX%02lX%02lX",
            lroundf(r * 255),
            lroundf(g * 255),
            lroundf(b * 255)];
}
```

Comment: At a guess, `subDataColor` wants a UIColor not a string, so you don't need the call to `hexStringFromColor`

Comment: Don't needlessly use `valueForKey:` to get a value from a dictionary. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a specific need to use KVC.

Comment: And since everyone and their dog uses valueForKey inappropriately, could you tell us who told you to use valueForKey? So maybe this nonsense can be eradicated once and for all? Isn't clearDic [key] much nicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change the below line of code

```
theGraphSubDataObj2.subDataColor = [clrDic objectForKey:key] ;
```

As `[clrDic valueForKey:key]` returns UIColor and `subDataColor` of Object is also UIColor then we can assign.

You are assigning `NSString` (`[self hexStringFromColor:[clrDic valueForKey:key]]`)to `UIColor` (subDataColor of Object)

Comment: Please fix this answer so it uses `objectForKey:` instead of incorrectly using `valueForKey:`.